# Why are there so many duplicates on my phone after using Link2SD

Tags: partitions, link2sd

I have noticed that the internal storage of my tablet is filling up even though I have tried to link as many of the apps as possible to the SD card using [Link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en_GB). I did a quick search for duplicates using [Search Duplicate File(Super)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.needjava.findersuper&hl=en_GB). What I found was that 1117 files where duplicated in both the `/mnt/internal_sd/` and `/mnt/external_sd` directories. Any idea why this has happened, and how I can free up this space?

I have searched both paths and none of them are symbolic links to the other. These are actual duplicates of the files.

[image]

I also did a listing using `adb shell` of both the `/mnt/internal_sd/...` and `/mnt/external_sd/...` paths and they both show up as **no symlink**. So as I understand the data must be duplicated. Unless someone can prove me wrong. A screenshot of Link2sd properties of the app is below this.

```
shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/bind/data/bbc.iplayer.android/files/b05zrbt6/                         <
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw 42955904 2016-01-17 11:38 bUnknown-90d1525f-3702-46eb-b1d7-a400a1b82884_b05zrbt4_1446672608107.ismv
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw    13348 2016-01-17 11:38 bUnknown-a46b887b-4a7a-4c8b-9e56-b0075cc3771a_b05zrbt4_1452896225597.xml
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw     1798 2016-01-17 11:38 details.xml
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw    37475 2016-01-17 11:38 p02tcd2c.jpg

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/bind/data/bbc.iplayer.android/files/                                  <
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-17 11:38 b05zrbt6
...
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/bind/data/bbc.iplayer.android/                               <
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 19:09 files

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/bind/data/                                             <
...
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2015-12-14 23:00 bbc.iplayer.android
...
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/bind/                    
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 12:09 data
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/Link2SD/                         
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2015-12-25 11:34 bind
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/external_sd/                                 
...
...
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2015-12-22 22:26 Link2SD
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/                                             
...
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 11:17 external_sd
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 11:17 internal_sd
...
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/Android/data/bbc.iplayer.android/files/b05zrbt6/                         <
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw 42955904 2016-01-17 11:38 bUnknown-90d1525f-3702-46eb-b1d7-a400a1b82884_b05zrbt4_1446672608107.ismv
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw    13348 2016-01-17 11:38 bUnknown-a46b887b-4a7a-4c8b-9e56-b0075cc3771a_b05zrbt4_1452896225597.xml
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw     1798 2016-01-17 11:38 details.xml
-rwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw    37475 2016-01-17 11:38 p02tcd2c.jpg

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/Android/data/bbc.iplayer.android/files/                                  <
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-17 11:38 b05zrbt6
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/Android/data/bbc.iplayer.android/                               <
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 19:09 files

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/Android/data/                                             <
...
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2015-12-14 23:00 bbc.iplayer.android
...
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/Android/                         
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2016-01-30 12:10 data
...

shell@rk312x:/data $ ls -alF /mnt/internal_sd/                                 
...
...
drwxrwx--- system   sdcard_rw          2015-11-24 18:10 Android
...
...
```

Link2sd iplayer link properties. 720MB is supposed to be linked to `external_sd` but shows up as duplicated in the listing above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This app may make new apk files like backup from apps or something like this , you can use another link to sd apps that arnot make new apk files.

Comment: What's the point of having an app that duplicates data that is supposed to save space? Find it hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

LINK2SD makes symbolic links, one file would just be a pointer to the real one. If you go to a terminal prompt and cd to that directory and do a "ls -alF" command, you will see one of these files is a zero size link, the other the actual file. This is how LINK2SD works.

Comment: I amended the question to include a listing as you said. I see no zero size link anywhere on the path. I used and example path for which I know there is supposed to be data on the internal and external sd partitions.